# PHP, Changing DIV using Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, flash

I have an index.php(Main), query.php and charts.php.

charts.php needs a file ("charts.xml") because inside the charts.php are some javascript codes and uses AC_FL_RunContent() to show the Flash Chart that required the charts.XML

the charts.XML can be produced using query.php when it is called

My main problem is. I cannot show the charts.php properly using the AJAX call when it is called in index.php but I can properly call the query.php properly. the Flash Chart wont show up but when I test run charts.php it runs fine, the Flash Chart shows properly.

Anything I am missing?

Comment: What does say the error console of Firefox, Chrome or Safi? Perhapbs there is a javascript error. Are you sure your 'index.php' contains all nessecary javascript code? Common mistakes are also using often wrong path(s).

Comment: no errors. it just doesnt show the graph. to test it out. i initiated an image on that DIV and the image was gone when the timer called the Function. meaning to say It changed the DIV. only the adobe flash graph doesnt show